Sessions killed when AG group connection terminated
We had a strange incident last night on our SQL Server 2014 AG group. We have a two-node group setup in asynchronous mode. The clock on the secondary was off by about 30 seconds and adjusted itself via NTP. This caused the AG group to fail and re-establish itself. That all makes sense to me.
What doesn't make sense is that when the AG group failed, all active SQL agent jobs running on the primary had their sessions killed. Why did this happen? We have no automatic failover configured and the jobs are not performing any queries on the secondary node.


What doesn't make sense is that when the AG group failed, all active SQL agent jobs running on the primary had their sessions killed. Why did this happen?

If a primary replica has a role change (it fails), all connections that were connected via the listener will be killed. Anything executing in the database will also be killed as the database will change state as part of the role change though their connection may still remain active if it was a physical instance connection.

Thanks Sean. I knew the listener part but not the killing of active sessions.
